# Determine path of swf file in C# application

Tags: c#, path, flash

I am using swf inside c# application. the problem is that, when I determine the path of swf file as static path "c:\path" , the file is worked. otherwise the file doesn't work.
I want to put the swf file inside the folder of application and run it in many devices.

Comment: it's not web application

Answer (score 2):

if it is windows form application, you can define a working directory path as below

```
private static string workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

by adding folder names you can access the folder you defined.

for example you can define path for swf files as below

```
string swfPath = workingDirectory + @"\SWFFILES"
```

Comment: For directory or file path use `Path.Combine` instead of doing `workingDirectory + @"\SWFFILES"`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the physical path to the virtual path of your web app. You can then append the swf filename to the end:

```
String path = Server.MapPath("swffolder\\");
```